# Modify elipsis in R

Tags: r

I have a problem with elipsis usecase. My function accepts list of objects, let's call them objects of class "X". Now, objects X are being processed inside of my function to class "Xs", so I have list of "Xs" objects. Function that I import from other package can compute multiple "Xs" objects at once but they have to be enumerated (elipsis mechanic), not passed as list. Is there a way how to solve it? I want something like this

```
examplefun <- function(charlist){
nums <- lapply(charlist, as.numeric)
sum(... = nums)
}
```

Of course example above throws an error but it shows what i want to achieve. I tried to unlist with recursive = FALSE ("X" and "Xs" are the list itself) but it does not work.

If there is no solution then:

Let's assume I decideed to accept ... insted of list of "X" objects. Can I modify elipsis elements (change them to "Xs") and then pass to function that accepts elipsis? So it will look like this:

```
examplefun2 <- function(...){
function that modify object in ... to "Xs" objects
sum(...)
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `do.call(sum, nums)`?

Comment: @Roland That was what I was looking for, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In your first function, just call `sum` directly because `sum` works correctly on vectors of numbers instead of individual numbers.

```
examplefun <- function (charlist) {
    nums <- vapply(charlist, as.numeric, numeric(1L))
    sum(nums)
}
```

(Note the use of `vapply` instead of `lapply`: `sum` expects an atomic vector, we can’t pass a list.)

In your second function, you can capture `...` and work with the captured variable:

```
examplefun2 <- function (...) {
    nums <- as.numeric(c(...))
    sums(nums)
}
```

For more complex arguments, Roland’s comment is a good alternative: Modify the function arguments as a list, and pass it to `do.call`.

Comment: Roland comment to my question was the most usefull, but thank You for your effort.